# PDF.js feeding base64 in DEFAULT_URL not working on Safari (mobile)

Tags: javascript, pdf, safari, mobile-safari, pdf.js

I am trying to display a PDF using PDF.js (1.1.215 & 1.1.366) by getting a PDF file from an XHR request in base64 format and feeding it into the DEFAULT_URL variable of the standard PDF.js viewer.

So far, I have tried 2 solutions:

1) Passing the base64 directly

```
//Get the document 
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","../../documents/get_document.php",false);
xmlhttp.send();

var pdf_document = xmlhttp.responseText;

var DEFAULT_URL = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdf_document;
```

RESULTS:

FF 40.0.2 --> OK

Chrome 44.0.2403.155 --> OK

Safari 8.0.6 + Mobile --> ERROR: unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjc......

2) converting the base64 string to an Uint8Array

```
function base64ToUint8Array(base64) {
var raw = atob(base64); //This is a native function that decodes a base64-encoded string.
var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(raw.length));
for(var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
uint8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
}
return uint8Array;
}

//Get the document 
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","../../documents/get_document.php",false);
xmlhttp.send();

var pdf_document = xmlhttp.responseText;

var DEFAULT_URL = base64ToUint8Array(pdf_document);
```

RESULTS:
All browsers --> viewer window OK but pdf not loading/showing (without error message)

From the the example at http://107.22.172.223:8877/c48a5fd7a46a111/examples/learning/helloworld64.html
I understood that there should be a way of just passing the atob(base64) string, but I haven't figured out how to do this in the default viewer.js (= setting it as DEFAULT_URL).

**Extra info**

I have asked this question also at the PDF.js github project, where the response was to alter the responseType and response properties of the XHR request.

**BUT**

- if I'm correct, this can only be done in case of an asynchronous request. And I do not see how I can feed the document into DEFAULT_URL of viewer.js using an asynchronous request (the document has to be fully received before the rest of the script can be executed)
- this does not explain why it works on FF/Chrome, but not in Safari

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Probably Safari does not support the loading from data protocol (via XHR). Did you complain to its vendor?

Comment: Hi async5, the strange thing here is that with PDF.js 1.0.277 and the exact same version of Safari it works without any problem. So something must have changed in PDF.js between 1.0.277 and 1.1.215.....

Comment: Also, it seems that the problem lies with the default viewer.js because the base64 example on http://107.22.172.223:8877/c48a5fd7a46a111/examples/learning/helloworld64.html works on all browsers (including Safari).